# Facebook messenger callback

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger

There are questions related to fb messenger. but as none answers my question, here it is.
I have been given a developer account for API to work on which is 'http'. Meaning I won't be able to use it as Callback URL. I am not authorized to request developer for https too.
How should I proceed?

Comment: You need https. Otherwise you will not get any callbacks

Comment: @WizKid Is there a way one could deploy bypass that API code and launch to Heroku app(which is https) and use it? Foolish question, though.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook requires that the callback url for receiving events use HTTPS as the scheme and specify a verify token in the app's webhook section.You should try to get the server you are working with to install the necessary SSL certificate(s) and update your webhook to point at it.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook requires https. You can use ngrok to convert your local URLs to https based public URL and use them on webhook subscription url.